# Are there any advantages of buying Ventra ticket/card over using a contactless credit card (in Chicago)?

Tags: usa, public-transport, payment-cards, chicago, illinois

As far as I understand, one can use contactless credit cards for riding buses and subway in Chicago, and the fares are the same. Are there any advantages of buying Ventra ticket/card over using a contactless credit card? (One scenario I can think of: maybe contactless cards are known to not work properly on all buses / at all stations? Are there any other scenarios?)

P.S. I'm talking about regular fares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer to the question in the title is no.

(To address the concern at the end of the question, I haven't had problems with using contactless credit cards on buses.)

Comment: Good to hear that Chicago joins London as the list of cities where a local useless piece of plastic is never required!

Comment: I see one reason. Some people do not like to hold their contactless card where others can easily snatch it. A prepaid card specific for travel is less a target.